# switching fields in filenames

Tags: python, shell, file-rename, batch-rename

How do I rename my files by switching different parts of the filename in a folder using either shell script, python or cmd window?

**Old filenames**
    partA_partB.pdf
    partC_partD.pdf
    partE_partF.pdf

**desired new filenames**
    partB_partA.pdf
    partD_partC.pdf
    partF_partE.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This should do it (in Python):

```
import os

directory = '/path/to/directory/the/files/are/in/'

for original_filename in os.listdir(directory):
    original_rootname, original_ext = os.path.splitext(original_filename)
    original_filepath = os.path.join(directory, original_filename)
    new_rootname = '_'.join(original_rootname.split('_')[::-1])
    new_filename = new_rootname + original_ext
    new_filepath = os.path.join(directory, new_filename)
    os.rename(original_filepath, new_filepath)
```

Comment: This will overwrite one or more files and eventually raise an exception if there are one or more pairs of files with names `X_Y` and a file `Y_X`, for any `X` or `Y`. Let me know if you need to check for that.

Comment: Thanks.  That works very well, except those files end with .pdf, so ".pdf" was also moved. I just started learning python a week or 2 ago.  I changed ...filename.split('_')[::-1]) to [::-4] (thinking that "-1" means from the end of the string) but it didn't work.

Comment: @ahsuen, `[::-1]` essentially means "reverse this thing". I'm reversing the list of filename sections, e.g. `['partA', 'partB']`.

Comment: @ahsuen, as for keeping the extensions at the end, I'll update my answer. You should update the question as well.

Comment: @ahsuen, I've updated the code. It now keeps the filename extension at the end, and still works for filenames without extensions. Please do update the question though :).

Comment: @Cypahse: An add-on question.  Say I want to delete the word "part" in all my filenames. Can I add these lines after new_filename line?     **new_filename2 = new_filename.replace("part", "")**  
**new_filepath = os.path.join(directory, new_filename2)**

Comment: @ahsuen, or just replace `new_filename = ...` with `new_filename = (new_rootname + original_ext).replace('part', '')`.

Comment: @ahsuen, by the way, for formatting code, you want the backtick (probably to the left of the `1` key on your keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

bash/ksh/zsh

```
for f in partA_partB partC_partD partE_partF; do
  IFS=_ read first second <<<"$f"
  echo mv "$f" "${second}_$first"
done
```

```
mv partA_partB partB_partA
mv partC_partD partD_partC
mv partE_partF partF_partE
```

use `for f in *; do` to iterate over your actual files.

Comment: If you have a file `abc_def` and a file `def_abc` already, the end result will be the deletion of `def_abc` and file `abc_def` will keep its name.